# Understanding A Short Proof on Integrable Functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, upper-lower-bounds, set-partition

Let Q be a rectangle in En and assume that f : Q → E is integrable.

(a) Show that if f(x) ≥ 0, for all x ∈ Q, then $\int Q f ≥ 0.$

(b) Show that if f(x) > 0 for all x ∈ Q, then $\int Q f > 0.$

Solution:
(a) For every partition P of Q, its lower sum L(f, P) is non-negative, so
$\int Q f $ ≥ L(f, P) ≥ 0.

I have a standard solution for (b) but I do not understand why I cannot solve (b) the same way as (a) as I showed above?

Answer (score 0):

You've omitted a step in the proof of (a): you must take the limit over partitions (as their mesh size tends to $0$, or however it's phrased for you). Fortunately, the limit of nonnegative numbers (when it exists, which is assumed here) is always nonnegative.

You're right that in (b), you get strict positivity for any particular partition. However, the limit of strictly positive numbers is not necessarily strictly positive. So this proof wouldn't give $\int_Q f > 0$, only $\int_Q f \ge 0$.

Comment: would you please elaborate what i have omitted in the step of (a)? this was a homework solution so I just copied it here thanks

Comment: Look at the definition of $\int_Q f$. It's not a lower sum for a single partition, so your proof as written doesn't say anything about $\int_Q f$. What is the exact definition of $\int_Q f$? (I'm asking Socratically; it is best if you take my input this far and put the pieces together yourself—you will learn far more robustly this way.)

Comment: $lim_{mesh->0} \sum f(xi)*(x_{i+1}-xi)$ is the definition but why would the limit not be strictly positive

Comment: ive been trying to make sense of it and i can't so if you can give some extra details itd be appreciate thanks

Comment: Ah, I see that the roadblock isn't with integrals and partitions, but limits themselves. Consider the sequence $a_n=\frac1n$. Each $a_n$ is strictly positive, but $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n=0$ is not strictly positive.