# Integrable nonnegative functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, functions, upper-lower-bounds

Let $Q$ be a rectangle in $E^n$ and assume that $f: Q\longrightarrow E$ is integrable.
Show that if $f(x) \geq 0$, for all $x \in Q$, then $\int Q f ≥ 0.$

**Solution**:

For every partition $P$ of $Q$, its lower sum $L(f, P)$ is non-negative, so
$\int Q f\geq L(f, P) \geq 0$.

I do not understand the solution fully is it missing a step using the definition $\lim_{\text{mesh}\to0}\sum f(_)\times(x_{i+1}−x_i)$? I do not know how to use the definition here.

Answer (score 0):

an integral is always larger then it's lower sum on any partition, that is what the proof is based on. If you want to prove it using the limit, you can show that each element in the sequence is none negative and therefore the limit is none negative.

Comment: what is the lower sum exactly here? why is it nonnegative

Comment: If ${\displaystyle f(x_{i}^{*})=\inf f([x_{i-1},x_{i}])}$ (that is, the infimum of f over $[x_{i-1},x_{i}])$, then S is defined to be an lower Riemann sum or lower Darboux sum. the reason it is none negative is that each element in the sum is none negative, becase it is an infimum on a group of none negative numbers (the function values on the interval)

Comment: can you take a look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3578313/understanding-a-short-proof-on-integrable-functions/3578317?noredirect=1#comment7357046_3578317? i do not understand if i use what you said, then i should be able to use the result for f>0 as well? but i cannot it seems

Comment: even if the function is strictly positive, the inf of its values on a given segment could still be zero (for example: $inf\left\{ \dfrac{1}{n}|n\in N\right\} =0$). That is why even for a strictly positive function, you will only be able to show that the lower sum is none negative.

Comment: sorry two more questions:
1) why is inf of that equal to 0? 
2) for the answer given in the link, the person said i am missing a step, or is he mistaken because like you mentioned for a), its either I used L(f,p) or the limit using mesh and I cannot use both? (so the other person who gave the answer got confused)